# Output of the statement is ambiguos

Tags: php

i have an expression in php code. it generate an output but i cannot understand the output of this statement. if some one explain me. that how the output is generating.

```
$var1=”a”;
$$var1=”b”;
 echo “$var1 $a”;
```

the out put of the above code is "a b". But how i don't know. pleaze somebody explain me.

Comment: [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Gotta love smart curly quotes `”`

Comment: You create a variable whose name is the value of another variable.

Comment: @Nasir For one thing, you need to change all `”` to `"` standard types. Those will actually echo `”`.

Comment: what about the echo statment the variable is with in double quouts

Comment: @Nasir Those are not standard types of double quotes. Those are known as "smart" or "Curly" quotes.

Comment: @Nasir When you run your code, which I doubt you already have, will be thrown the following error message: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$var1' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in...`

Comment: @Fred-ii-, sir i get the point thank you.

Comment: @Nasir And if you change those to standard quotes like this `"` and run your code again, the output will now be this `a b`

Comment: @Fred-ii- sir con you give vote for my post

Comment: @Nasir Why an upvote? I see no actual problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$var1="a";`

- $var1 becomes "a"

`$$var1="b";`

- `$var1` is `a`, so after replacing $var1 by `a` we get:

`$a="b" ;`

- `$var1` is now `"a"`, and `$a` is `"b"`

`echo "$var1 $a";`

- Replace `$var1` with "a", and `$a` with `"b"`, and we get:

`a b`

Answer (score 1):

the right '$' is parsed first,and $$var1 change to $a. So,in deed,it is $a = "b";